# Ruby on rails associations - User (devise) can 'create a team' or 'join team' after sign up and log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations

Hey guys im working on a rails application where users that have successfully signed up and logged in to their dashboard can create a team and become the leader (invite others to join via email, delete existing members etc.) or join an existing team as a member.( can only view other members and information about themselves) I'm using the Devise gem for user login / sign up since it has a lot of what i need. A team has one manager and has many members. Heres what ive tried, users belong to teams, and teams have many users. Ive also tried the association, Users have one team and teams have many users but one manager. I'm very confused thanks again.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable 
   validates_presence_of :phone, :city, :state, :street, :zip, presence: true, on: :create
      has_one :team     
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "team_name"
    t.string "team_statement"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_teams_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "middlename"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "street"
    t.string "zip"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
   devise_for :users, path: 'users' , controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", confirmations: 'users/confirmations', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

Comment: There is no one question. What problem do you solve?

Comment: My question is what is the best way of handling this situation, ive provided the code above to show what ive tried. Ive described what my issues are. @Neodelf

Comment: It depends on what screens do you have. It can be a form on the signup page (where user immediately choose what he or she wants - becomes a leader of a team or create a new one) or page after successfully login/signup process.

Comment: @Neodelf Thanks for the quick reply, the users choose whether they would like to Create a new team and become the leader, or join an existing team after sign up and logged in

Comment: Just you should create a new page (route, controller, view and action) and create form. Did you try it?

Comment: @Neodelf Yes i have got all the proper routes controllers and views, i think where my confusion lies is in the proper associations to make? is this where i need to use a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' association? again im trying to have the user who creates a team become the leader and if the user decides to join a team they will see all current teams and request to join

Answer (score 0):

You just add integer field `leader_id` to `teams` table. Also, you should add this row to `team.rb`:

```
belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'User'
```

that helps you find a leader from a team (like `team.leader`).
You should not use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

Comment: awesome this is currently working but how will but how will i add more users to teams as members?

Comment: just use added field `team_id` on `users` table.
For example:
You have records: User id: 1, team_id: 1, ... ; Team id: 1, leader_id: 1. With them you can use `team.users`, `team.leader` and `user.team` methods

Comment: Bare with me i have updated the code above, am i still doing something wrong? @Neodelf

Comment: Add the code above and methods in the comment above will work

Comment: i have updated the code in my original question above, am i still doing something wrong ? @Neodelf